# Proper implementation of custom bindings on a custom control

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa-bindings, foundation

Since all those calendar-style `NSDatePicker`s take a lot of space, I've decided to put them in a view controller, use a button to display the date itself, and upon click use an `NSPopover` to display the calendar in a popup.

I then use bindings to link the `NSButton` subclass's `date` property with an `NSArrayController`'s current selection's `NSDate`-typed property. Which then propagates into the calendar-style date picker, and the other way around. For the 'other way around', instead of using KVO, I simply implement custom setters, so if someone sets the value of `date` on the button or on the calendar view controller (perhaps the binding to the array controller sets the button's value so the button sets the calendar view controller's value; perhaps the change on calendar sets view controller's value; who knows) -- then I propagate the change.

It all ends up working nicely… except for one thing.

Multiple selection.

You see, immediately after the user performs multiple selection, the system rightfully decides to tell my button that the selection is now `nil`. To propagate the change, I tell all my bound observers that the value has changed to `nil`. One of these bound observers is the `NSArrayController`, which currently has multiple items selected.

What's the problem? Setting current selection's bound keypath to `nil` results in setting all dates in the selection to `nil`… propagating the change into the database. And the user didn't even set the value to `nil` - it was propagated as a result of simply making multiple selection, not making any choices, and it's supposed to be used solely for purposes of displaying this value.

Thankfully, right now I have no need to support multiple selection for these calendars. I simply detect the `NSMultipleSelectionMarker` by comparing observed object's observed key path's value using `isEqual:`). If multiple selection is done, I do apply the value to the ivar, but I don't 'bidirectionally' notify other bound objects of the change.

But -- if I wanted to support the user selecting several documents, and then changing all of their issue dates at once (as the user would be able to do using bindings implementation done in standard `NSDatePicker`, `NSTextField` et al) -- how would I go about doing so without the action of creating multiple selection also propagating false changes such as setting `nil` to all selected objects?

*(Note: While the question was written to reflect my current need in which I reuse standard controls: buttons, popovers, date pickers -- it is NOT limited to such reuse. I may want to implement a completely custom function-graph widget tomorrow which needs bidirectional Cocoa bindings.)*

Here are a few chunks of relevant code for the `IRDatePopoverEditorButton`:

```
+ (void)initialize
{
    [super initialize];

    [self exposeBinding:@"date"];
    [self exposeBinding:@"minDate"];
    [self exposeBinding:@"maxDate"];
}
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    // …        
    [self establishBindings];

}

- (void)establishBindings
{
    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"date", @"minDate", @"maxDate", nil];

    NSDictionary * options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSContinuouslyUpdatesValueBindingOption,
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSConditionallySetsEnabledBindingOption,
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSValidatesImmediatelyBindingOption,
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], NSRaisesForNotApplicableKeysBindingOption,
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], NSAllowsEditingMultipleValuesSelectionBindingOption, 
                              nil];

    // This code allows creation of bindings via interface builder without actual
    // support for custom bindings in IB. I hijack the 'user defined runtime attributes'
    // and define binding keypath there, and I use an IBOutlet to define a binding
    // target.
    for(NSString *key in keys)
    {
        id bindingTarget = [self valueForKey:[key stringByAppendingString:@"BindingTarget"]];;
        id bindingKeyPath = [self valueForKey:[key stringByAppendingString:@"BindingKeyPath"]];;
        if (!bindingTarget || !bindingKeyPath)
            continue;

        [bindingTarget valueForKeyPath:bindingKeyPath];

        [self bind:key
          toObject:[self valueForKey:[key stringByAppendingString:@"BindingTarget"]]
       withKeyPath:[self valueForKey:[key stringByAppendingString:@"BindingKeyPath"]]
           options:options];

    }
}

// one of the custom setters
- (void)setDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    if(_date == date)
        return;

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"date"];
    [date retain];
    [_date release];
    _date = date;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"date"];

    NSDictionary * infoForBinding = [self infoForBinding:@"date"];
    if(infoForBinding && [infoForBinding objectForKey:NSObservedObjectKey])
    {
        id observedObject = [infoForBinding objectForKey:NSObservedObjectKey];
        NSString * observedKeyPath = [infoForBinding objectForKey:NSObservedKeyPathKey];

        if([[observedObject valueForKeyPath:observedKeyPath] isEqual:NSMultipleValuesMarker])
        {
            // This is needed because, when performing multiple selection,
            // we get called with setDate:nil. Then we blindly apply this to
            // the entire selection.
            // For our needs, it's enough to block applying values to multiple
            // selection. But it's not a correct solution.

            // FIXME: we currently block editing of multiple selection.
            NSLog(@"Not applying value for keypath %@ to %@; currently multiple items are selected", observedKeyPath, observedObject);
        }
        else
        {
            [observedObject setValue:date forKeyPath:observedKeyPath];
        }
    }

    if(self.date)
        if(self.formatter)
            [self setTitle:[self.formatter stringForObjectValue:date]];
        else
            [self setTitle:[date description]];
    else
        [self setTitle:@"-"];
}
```